# Working TicTacTo CheckWin function?

Tags: c, comparison, logic, conditional-statements, tic-tac-toe

So I'm working on writing a C program that will play TicTacTo against the user. However, I'm having issues with the function that checks if there is a winner. It doesn't seem to function at all. The game just continues when there are 3 in a row. Here's the relevant code.

This is in my main function:

```
do {
    humanChoice(); // let the user make a play  
    computerChoice(); // does nothing at the moment
    gameStatus = checkWin(); // returns 1 if it finds a winner
} while(gameStatus==0);
```

The humanChoice plays an "X" in the array at the position the user selected. This has been tested thoroughly and works perfectly. And then the checkWin() function:

```
int checkWin() {

if (
    matrix[0][0] == matrix[0][1] == matrix[0][2] || // 1st row
    matrix[1][0] == matrix[1][1] == matrix[1][2] || // 2nd row
    matrix[2][0] == matrix[2][1] == matrix[2][2] || // 3rd row

    matrix[0][0] == matrix[1][0] == matrix[2][0] || // 1st column
    matrix[0][1] == matrix[1][1] == matrix[2][1] || // 2nd column
    matrix[0][2] == matrix[1][2] == matrix[2][2] || // 3rd column

    matrix[0][0] == matrix[1][1] == matrix[2][2] || // left to right diagonal
    matrix[0][2] == matrix[1][1] == matrix[2][0]    // right to left diagonal
) {
    printf("Win! Game Over!");
    return(1);
}

return(0);
}
```

I'm using the following 2 dimensional array for my "matrix":

```
char matrix[3][3];
```

I realize that right now the program can't distinguish between a computer win and a user win. Right now that's irrelevant. I just need it to check for a win in general.

Anything you notice?

Comment: If your question has been answer, you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` operator returns `true` if the left and right hand operands are equal.

`a == b` will return `true` when they are equal.
`b == c` will return `true` when they are equal.

`a == b == c` however, will return true when `a == b` evaluates to the same value as `c`.

You will want to use `(a == b) && (b == c)` to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Interesting! I've worked with C for about a year now and never came across this. You learn something new all the time. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An expression like `a == b == c` is not the same as `a == b && b == c`. That's why your function doesn't work as intended.

Comment: `a == b` is a boolean expression which is `1` if a=b, and `0` otherwise. When you write `a == b == c`, you compare the result of the first comparison (which is 0 or 1) to `c`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (matrix[0][0] == matrix[0][1] == matrix[0][2]) ...
```

is different than:

```
if (matrix[0][0] == matrix[0][1] && matrix[0][1] == matrix[0][2]) ...
```

---

In the first case, the first comparison is evaluated at first, making it equivalent to something like:

```
int b = matrix[0][0] == matrix[0][1];
if (b == matrix[0][2]) ...
```

comparison returns `0` or `1`, not the value that is being compared (unlike assignment operator, which returns the value that has been assigned).

Comment: What would the difference be?